# Insert current time with NOW() or TIME()

Tags: php, mysql

Which of the method is better to insert current time in mySQL.

PHP: `time()` in db column type `INT(10)`

or

MySQL: `Now()` in db type `(datetime)`

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second one is generally better as you don't need to convert it to a proper datetime before using other MySQL datetime functions on it.

Comment: is it so that `time()` returns the current time of server, while `now()` returns the current time of user?

Comment: @Roman `NOW()` returns current MySQL server time and `TIME()` is something different, [according to docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time).

Answer (score 2):

storing a datetime is more useful for things like finding how many days have past. you can use all of date/time mysql functions in your queries.

Answer (score 2):

The second - Now in datetime. Time returns a string. You'd need datetime most likely for different time-based calculations, plus there are tons of way to retrieve and format it with your queries.